# Allow users to download files from link if they check "Agree to Terms" box or radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I would like to setup a file download page similar to [the one here on Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

**How do I recreate this?**

I'm not familiar with writing javascript, but I see that the are using javascript to display the table and control the popup and also replace the link once the "Agree to Terms" radio button has been selected. They're using this code:

```
// Dynamically generated download page for OTN. 
// Aurelio Garcia-Ribeyro, 2012-05-21, based off of pre-existing code for OTN license acceptance

// Only the 'downloads' array should need to be modified, unless the look/feel needs to be changed in the body at the bottom

// 'downloads' is an array of releases, using the CDS part number as the key for each release. Each release is also an array of meta-data for that release. Finally, there is a 3rd nested array of files to be offered in the release.

// downloads[product][path] will assumed to be the path for each file. NOT YET IMPLEMENTED: Unless downloads[product]['files']['path'] is defined. 
// The filename will assumed to be the key for path from downloads[product]['files']. NOT YET IMPLEMENTED: Unless downloads[product]['files']['filename'] is defined. 

var page_title = "Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads";
var page_blurb = '<p>Thank you for downloading this release of the Java<sup>TM</sup> Platform, Standard Edition Development Kit (JDK<sup>TM</sup>). The JDK is a development environment for building applications, applets, and components using the Java programming language.</p> <p>The JDK includes tools useful for developing and testing programs written in the Java programming language and running on the Java platform.<br></p><div>See also:</div> <div> <div> <ul> <li><a href="http://myprofile.oracle.com/">Java Developer Newsletter</a>&nbsp;(tick the checkbox under Subscription Center &gt; Oracle Technology News)</li> <li><a href="http://events.oracle.com/search/search?start=&amp;pageHitCount=10&amp;group=Events&amp;keyword=java">Java Developer Day hands-on workshops (free) and other events</a></li> <li><a href="http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamagazine/index.html">Java Magazine</a></li> </ul> JDK MD5 <a href="https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u31checksum.html" target="_blank">Checksum</a> </div> <br> <b>Looking for JDK 8 on ARM?</b> <br>JDK 8 for ARM downloads have moved to the <a href="/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html">JDK 8 for ARM download page.</a></div>';



var downloads = new Array();
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR'] = new Array();
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['title'] = "Java SE Development Kit 8u31";
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['lictitle'] = "Oracle Binary Code License Agreement for Java SE";
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['licpath'] = "/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license";
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files'] = new Array();

downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-i586.rpm'] = { "title":"Linux x86", "size":"135.24 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-linux-i586.rpm"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-i586.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Linux x86", "size":"154.91 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-linux-i586.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-x64.rpm'] = { "title":"Linux x64", "size":"135.62 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.rpm"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Linux x64", "size":"153.45 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-macosx-x64.dmg'] = { "title":"Mac OS X x64", "size":"209.17 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-macosx-x64.dmg"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9.tar.Z'] = { "title":"Solaris SPARC 64-bit (SVR4 package)", "size":"136.91 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9.tar.Z"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Solaris SPARC 64-bit", "size":"97.11 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-x64.tar.Z'] = { "title":"Solaris x64 (SVR4 package)", "size":"137.51 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-solaris-x64.tar.Z"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-x64.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Solaris x64", "size":"94.82 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-solaris-x64.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-windows-i586.exe'] = { "title":"Windows x86", "size":"157.96 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-windows-i586.exe"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-windows-x64.exe'] = { "title":"Windows x64", "size":"170.36 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13/jdk-8u31-windows-x64.exe"};



downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR'] = new Array();
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['title'] = "Java SE Development Kit 8u31 Demos and Samples Downloads";
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['lictitle'] = "Oracle BSD License.";
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['licpath'] = "/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/oraclebsd-1603217.txt";
//downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['licNoAccept'] = true;
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files'] = new Array();


downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-i586-demos.rpm'] = { "title":"Linux x86", "size":"58.65 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-linux-i586-demos.rpm"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-i586-demos.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Linux x86", "size":"58.5 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-linux-i586-demos.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-x64-demos.rpm'] = { "title":"Linux x64", "size":"58.71 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-linux-x64-demos.rpm"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-linux-x64-demos.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Linux x64", "size":"58.56 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-linux-x64-demos.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-macosx-x86_64-demos.zip'] = { "title":"Mac OS X", "size":"59.22 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-macosx-x86_64-demos.zip"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9-demos.tar.Z'] = { "title":"Solaris SPARC 64-bit", "size":"13.51 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9-demos.tar.Z"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9-demos.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Solaris SPARC 64-bit", "size":"9.27 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-solaris-sparcv9-demos.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-x64-demos.tar.Z'] = { "title":"Solaris x64", "size":"13.52 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-solaris-x64-demos.tar.Z"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-solaris-x64-demos.tar.gz'] = { "title":"Solaris x64", "size":"9.25 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-solaris-x64-demos.tar.gz"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-windows-i586-demos.zip'] = { "title":"Windows x86", "size":"60.33 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-windows-i586-demos.zip"};
downloads['jdk-8u31-demos-oth-JPR']['files']['jdk-8u31-windows-x64-demos.zip'] = { "title":"Windows x64", "size":"60.43 MB","filepath":"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31-b13-demos/jdk-8u31-windows-x64-demos.zip"};


function disableAnchor(obj, disable){
  if(disable){
    var href = obj.getAttribute("href");
    if(href && href != "" && href != null){
       obj.setAttribute('href_bak', href);
    }
    // obj.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/sorry-150381.html');
    obj.removeAttribute('href');
    obj.setAttribute('class', 'boldbodylink');
  } else {
    obj.setAttribute('href', obj.getAttribute('href_bak'));
    obj.setAttribute('class', 'boldbodylink');
  }
}

function disableAnchorByName(anchorname, disable){
//  var use_gebi=false;
    var o=null;
    // if (document.getElementById) { use_gebi=true; }
    // Logic to find position
    // if (use_gebi) {
    //  o=document.getElementById(anchorname);
    // } else {
    for (var i=0; i<document.anchors.length; i++) {
        if (document.anchors[i].name==anchorname) { o=document.anchors[i]; break; }
    }
    disableAnchor(o, disable);
}

function disableAnchorByName(doc, anchorname, disable, enabledHref, onclickFtn){
    var use_gebi=false;
    var o=null;
    for (var i=0; i<doc.anchors.length; i++) {
        if (doc.anchors[i].name==anchorname) { o=doc.anchors[i]; break; }
    }
    disableAnchor(o, disable, enabledHref, onclickFtn);
}

function disableAnchor( obj, disable, enabledHref, onclickFtn ){
  if(disable){
    obj.onclick = onclickFtn;
    // obj.setAttribute('onclick', disabledHref );
    // obj.removeAttribute('href');
    // obj.setAttribute('href', onclickFtn );
    obj.setAttribute('class', 'boldbodylink');
  } else {
    obj.setAttribute('href', enabledHref );
    obj.onclick = null;
    obj.setAttribute('class', 'boldbodylink');
  }
}

function disableDownloadAnchors(doc, disabled, part){

    var agreementPrompt = new Function( "alert('Sorry, you must accept the License Agreement before downloading.');" );

        if (downloads[part]['title']) {     
            for(var b in downloads[part]['files']) {
                if (downloads[part]['files'][b]['title']) {
                    disableAnchorByName(doc, part + 'XXX' + b, disabled, downloads[part]['files'][b]['filepath'], agreementPrompt); 
                }
            }
        }
}

function youMustAgreePrompt(){
    alert('Sorry, you must accept the License Agreement before downloading.');
}

function acceptAgreement(windowRef, part){
    var doc = windowRef.document;
    disableDownloadAnchors(doc, false, part);
    hideAgreementDiv(doc, part);
    writeSessionCookie( 'oraclelicense', 'accept-securebackup-cookie' );
}

function declineAgreement(windowRef, part){
    var doc = windowRef.document;
    disableDownloadAnchors(doc, true, part);
    writeSessionCookie( 'oraclelicense', 'decline' );
    // forward();
}

function showAgreement(part){
    window.open(downloads[part]['licpath'],'LicenseAgreement','status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=400,top=150,left=400');
}

function showAgreement2(part){
    window.open(downloads[part]['licpath2'],'LicenseAgreement','status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=400,top=150,left=400');
}

function forward(){
    location.href="http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/sorry-150381.html";
}

function hideAgreementDiv(doc, part) {
    if (doc.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        doc.getElementById('agreementDiv' + part).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        doc.getElementById('thankYouDiv' + part).style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        if (doc.layers) { // Netscape 4  BROKEN?
            doc.getElementById('agreementDiv' + part).visibility = 'hidden';
            doc.getElementById('thankYouDiv' + part).visibility = 'visible';
        } else { // IE 4  BROKEN?
            doc.all.getElementById('agreementDiv' + part).style.visibility = 'hidden';
            doc.all.getElementById('thankYouDiv' + part).style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}

function resetAgreementForm(){
    //alert('here 1');
    var cookie = getCookieValue('oraclelicense');
    var myRadios = document.forms['agreementForm']['agreement'];

    if(cookie == null){
        document.forms['agreementForm'].reset();
    } else if(cookie == 'accept-securebackup-cookie') {
        myRadios[0].checked = 'true';
        acceptAgreement(part);
    } else if(cookie == 'decline'){
        myRadios[1].checked = 'true';
    }
}



document.write('<a name="top" id="top"></a><h1>' + page_title + '</h1><br />'); 
document.write(page_blurb + '<br/>'); 


// Add this section in if there are multiple products and you want an anchored table of contents at the top
// document.write('<UL>'); 
// for(var d in downloads) {
//  if (downloads[d]['files']) {
//      document.write('<li><a href="#' + d + '">' + downloads[d]['title'] + '</a></li>');
//  }
// }
// document.write('</ul>'); 

for(var d in downloads) {
    if (downloads[d]['files']) {
        document.write('<br /><table width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 1px;"><tbody>');
        if (downloads[d]['title']) document.write('<tr bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><a id="' + d + '" name="' + d + '"></a><h3>&nbsp;' + downloads[d]['title'] + '</h3></td></tr>');

        if (downloads[d]['lictitle'])
          if (downloads[d]['licNoAccept']) {
            document.write('<tr bgcolor="#d0d0d0"><th colspan="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><div class="lic_div">');
            document.write('<BR><p>' + downloads[d]['title'] + ' are released under the <a href="' +  downloads[d]['licpath'] + '">' +  downloads[d]['lictitle'] + '</a></p>');
            document.write('</div></th></tr>');               
          } else {
            document.write('<tr bgcolor="#d0d0d0"><th colspan="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><div class="lic_div">');
            document.write('<p>You must accept the <a href="javascript:showAgreement(\'' + d + '\');">' +  downloads[d]['lictitle'] + '</a>');
            if (downloads[d]['lictitle2']) document.write(' and <a href="javascript:showAgreement2(\'' + d + '\');">' +  downloads[d]['lictitle2'] + '</a>');       
            document.write(' to download this software.</p>');
            document.write('<div align="left" id="agreementDiv' + d + '"><form name="agreementForm' + d + '" method="post" action="radio" class="lic_form"><input type="radio" value="on" name="agreement' + d + '" onClick="acceptAgreement(window.self, \'' + d + '\');" /> &nbsp;Accept License Agreement&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" value="on" name="agreement' + d + '" onClick="declineAgreement(window.self, \'' + d + '\');" checked="checked" /> &nbsp; Decline License Agreement</form></div>');
            document.write('<div style="visibility: hidden;" id="thankYouDiv' + d + '" class="com_msg">Thank you for accepting the ' + downloads[d]['lictitle'] + '; you may now download this software.<br/></div>');
            document.write('<br />&nbsp;</div></th></tr>');     
      }

        document.write('<tr bgcolor="#e0e0e0"><th cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><h4>&nbsp;Product / File Description</h4></th><th><h4>File Size</h4></th><th><h4>Download</h4></th></tr>');

        for(var e in downloads[d]['files']) {
            if (downloads[d]['files'][e]['title']) {
                if (downloads[d]['lictitle'] && !(downloads[d]['licNoAccept'])) 
                    document.write('<tr valign="top" style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; margin-bottom:1px;"><td>&nbsp;' + downloads[d]['files'][e]['title'] + '</td><td align="right">' + downloads[d]['files'][e]['size'] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a name="' + d + 'XXX' + e + '" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="youMustAgreePrompt();" id="' + d + 'XXX' + e + '"> <img src="/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/digitalasset/115899.gif"> ' + e + '</a></td></tr>');
                else
                    document.write('<tr valign="top" style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; margin-bottom:1px;"><td>&nbsp;' + downloads[d]['files'][e]['title'] + '</td><td align="right">' + downloads[d]['files'][e]['size'] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a name="' + d + 'XXX' + e + '" href="' + downloads[d]['files'][e]['filepath'] + '" id="' + d + 'XXX' + e + '"> <img src="/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/digitalasset/115899.gif"> <strong>' + e + '</strong></a></td></tr>');

            }
        }
        // document.write('<tr><td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" align="center"><em><a href="#top">Back to top</a></em></td></tr>');
        document.write('</tbody></table>');
    }
}
```

Then it looks like they have cookies to determine if you've already agreed to the terms or not, so you can download all the file links.

It seems this is the download cookies code:

```
function writeSessionCookie (cookieName, cookieValue) {
    if (testSessionCookie()) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30*60*1000));
        document.cookie = escape(cookieName) + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + "; domain=.oracle.com; path=/; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

function getCookieValue (cookieName) {
  var exp = new RegExp (escape(cookieName) + "=([^;]+)");
  if (exp.test (document.cookie + ";")) {
    exp.exec (document.cookie + ";");
    return unescape(RegExp.$1);
  }
  else return false;
}

function testSessionCookie () {
  document.cookie ="testSessionCookie=Enabled";
  if (getCookieValue ("testSessionCookie")=="Enabled")
    return true
  else
    return false;
}

function testPersistentCookie () {
  writePersistentCookie ("testPersistentCookie", "Enabled", "minutes", 1);
  if (getCookieValue ("testPersistentCookie")=="Enabled")
    return true
  else
    return false;
}

function writePersistentCookie (CookieName, CookieValue, periodType, offset) {

  var expireDate = new Date ();
  offset = offset / 1;

  var myPeriodType = periodType;
  switch (myPeriodType.toLowerCase()) {
    case "years":
      expireDate.setYear(expireDate.getFullYear()+offset);
      break;
    case "months":
      expireDate.setMonth(expireDate.getMonth()+offset);
      break;
    case "days":
      expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+offset);
      break;
    case "hours":
      expireDate.setHours(expireDate.getHours()+offset);
      break;
    case "minutes":
      expireDate.setMinutes(expireDate.getMinutes()+offset);
      break;
    default:
      alert ("Invalid periodType parameter for writePersistentCookie()");
      break;
  }

  document.cookie = escape(CookieName ) + "=" + escape(CookieValue) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
}

function deleteCookie (cookieName) {
  if (getCookieValue (cookieName)) writePersistentCookie (cookieName,"Pending delete","years", -1);
    return true;
}
```

I tried using the javascript code in a jsfiddle, but it didn't seem to work, so I assumed I was missing something.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this effect?

Comment: You cant directly copy and paste code and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin:

```
if($.cookie("accepted")){
    $("#terms").hide();
}

$('#accept').click(function() {
    $.cookie("accepted", true, { expires: 9999 });
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/jv6L8ncL/ (see External Resources)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. I greatly appreciate it! I will check it out.

Comment: This wasn't the exact answer for achieving the example, but I decide to use this method to show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

You should be working in a particular process

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" value=true>
<button id="startDownload">Download</button>
```

// Function to set and get Cookie

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

// Function to execute when user clicks on download button

```
$("#startDownload").click(function(){
// Condition to check radio button and cookie parameter

    if($("#radio").val() && getCookie("check_radio"))
    {
    // Proceed to download
    }
    else if($("#radio").val())
    {
    setCookie("check_radio", true, 365); // Set Cookie
    // Proceed to download
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Please confirm terms and condition");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I greatly appreciate it! I will check it out.

Comment: FYI: I tried this code in jsfiddle and couldn't understand how to get it to work and where to insert the links. I'm sure this will help someone though who knows more than I do.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to learn JavaScript. It's unlikely that you'll be able to implement functionality by copying and pasting.

For this purpose you'll need to know how to check/set cookies and do some DOM manipulation.

Your logic would be

1. Check if the accept cookie is set.
2. If it is set, replace all the text with the actual links. Done.
3. If it is not set, display the text instead of the links.
4. When the accept is clicked, set the cookie and do Step 2. Done.